# Word or phrase for "online supporting documents"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, sentence, conversation

In a conversation on a particular topic, I want to ask the other person to provide online supporting documents about his views on the topic.

They may be *websites* or *blogs* or *wiki* etc, but they should have global acceptance. I mean those documents are hosted or run by a globally accepted consortium, or an enterprise or may be it belongs to some government.

In short, to provide online documents that have global acceptance for his views on that topic.

So what would be the appropriate *word* or *phrase* I should use to say this sentence?

Comment: The "*standard literature*"? The "*official documentation*"?

Comment: @DanBron hey thanks, official documentation seems better.

Comment: Please do not use backticks or capitalization for emphasis: use italic instead.  And ease up on the ugly bold.  And perhaps spellcheck your username.

Comment: hehehyaha, alright @tchrist I'll be careful on formatting, but a _beginer_ is always a _beginer_.

Comment: "References" seems fitting...

Answer (score 1):

The word you want isn't *official* - it's...

> *"Please provide links to [**authoritative**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/authoritative) sources supporting your argument"*

Obviously, *authoritative* there means *considered to be accurate and knowledgeable by people who are themselves experts in the relevant field*, not *endorsed by some official body or "authority"*.

As has been stated, you can also use *credible* in such contexts, but I think most people would agree that's a more "loaded" term which tends to imply *...but be aware that I might classify your cited sources as "not credible" to me*. The more neutral alternative is [*accredited*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/accredited), but that has the same problems as *official* (they're simply not appropriate terms for things like blogs and most public-access wikis, etc.).

Comment: I think it can be _official_ for example a document on a Government's website.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: how would you apply "*authoritative*" to the actual documents or literature? Somehow, "*authoritative* documentation" doesn't ring right to me.

Comment: @Dan Bron: I wouldn't use the word *documentation* in OP's context in the first place, since he wants it to include things like blogs. But *authoritative sources* is a very common collocation.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you are looking for "credible online references".